# Unit testing AngularJS Directive with isolated scope - how to get bindings to output?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-runner

I'm really needing advice and guidance on testing AngularJS directives with Isolated Scope.

Say I have the following directive (which works):

```
angular.module('myApp')

    .directive('pageNav', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                title: '@'
            },
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: 'pageNav.html',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                if (attrs.pageNav == 'translucent') {
                    element.find('nav').addClass('newClass');
                }
             }
        };
    })
;
```

This is the template URL code:

```
<nav class="pageNav">
    <div class="content">
        <h1 ng-if="title">{{ title }}</h1>

        <div class="contentRight" ng-transclude></div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

now I have the following test

```
describe('Page Nav Directive', function() {

    var $scope,
        element;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    beforeEach(module('pageNav.html'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
        $scope = $rootScope;
        $scope.title = "hey hey, my my";
        element = angular.element('<div page-nav></div>');
        // element = angular.element('<div page-nav title="hey hey, my my"></div>');
        $compile(element)($scope);

        $scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should render the directive', function() {
       // this test will fail if I un-comment the element above
       expect(element.find('div').eq(1).attr('class')).toBe('contentRight');
    });

    it('should render a title', function() {
        // this test will pass if I un-comment the element above
       expect(element.find('h1').eq(0).text()).toBe('hey hey, my my');
    });

})

;
```

Now I don't understand why the second test fails with the first element even though I have set the `$scope.title` (for some reason the binding `{{ title }}` isn't rendered). Now if I put the `$scope.title` on the element as an attribute the second test will pass as the rendering works, but the first test fails? I even changed the first test to

```
expect(element.scope().find('div').eq(1).attr('class')).toBe('contentRight');
```

when using the I put the `$scope.title` on the element as an attribute however this failed too.

I am finding little or no good documentation on testing AngularJS Directives with isolated scopes and I am pulling my hair out. Any guidance, info or explanations to the problems I have would be most appreciated.

Comment: Could you perhaps create a jsffidle for this. It'll help us help you quicker

Comment: Here's a primitive fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/itakesmack/ecfpz/

Comment: Have you checked that the fiddle works?

Comment: I've just added the code above, as I'm using karma/jasmine, I was hoping someone could just explain the issues with rendering and scope than amend the code.

Comment: I know but it's easier to explain once it's been debugged and working ;)

Comment: try... http://jsfiddle.net/itakesmack/ecfpz/6/

Comment: **setting `$scope.title` (for some reason the binding `{{ title }}` isn't rendered)**. Sure, because you're using `title: '@'`, `@` means you bind with **static string**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem 1:** setting `$scope.title` (for some reason the binding `{{ title }}` isn't rendered)

Sure, because you're using `title: '@'`, `@` means you bind with static string.

**Problem 2:**

You're using `templateUrl`, the browser has to initiate **an ajax request** to load the template, it means that the directive's template **is not loaded yet** in the current function, **has to wait for the ajax request** to finish => the result is unpredictable.

As this [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/iiQJGOTDYCHrpbRrqaSd?p=preview) shows, if I check the compiled html immediately in the same function, I see that it's not compiled. In order to show you that the templateUrl is correct and will be loaded later, i added one more [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/5e9OKh8SWlsgsiqj3DLa?p=preview) using `console.log` with an **object reference** to prove it

If I use inline `template`, as in this [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/iiQJGOTDYCHrpbRrqaSd?p=preview), the template is replaced (but not compiled).

**Problem 3:**

Angular js compile function does not finish in the current function, you may need to use $timeout to schedule it for the next cycle. [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/eLTcfqw9quDJGaMotwbb?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks that's great, can I ask what it would mean if I used title: '=' or title: '&' - I can put this is a separate question

Comment: @Mike Sav: check my updated with problem number 3. If you need to bind it with a property of your scope, you should use `title: '='`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have other tests that use "=" that also don't bind, that's why I asked.